# Apache Jackrabbit throws 403 in WebDAV anonymous access

Tags: apache, webdav, http-status-code-403, jackrabbit, jcr

I configured Apache Jackrabbit 2.6.3 to use WebDAV in an anonymous mode (empty credentials are mapped to `anonymous:anonymous`).

If I click on a direct link to some file (e.g. JPG or DOC) HTTP 403 error is thrown by GlassFish server. If I press <kbd>F5</kbd>, 403 is still there.

[image: 403 error]

BUT if I simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in address bar in my browser on the same URL, everything is OK, and resource is accessible.

I think that only difference is a referrer in the HTTP header.
I searched for any information about a similar problem, but I couldn't find anything.

Does anybody have some idea how to force WebDAV (or Jackrabbit) to serve files in the anonymous mode despite the referrer or any other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
In `web.xml` file in section `WebDAV` the following part must be uncommented:

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>csrf-protection</param-name>
        <param-value>disabled</param-value>
</init-param>
```

With `disabled` as `param-value`.

As description says:

> Defines the behaviour of the referrer based CSRF protection
>      1) If omitted or left empty the (default) behaviour is to allow only requests with
>         an empty referrer header or a referrer host equal to the server host
>      2) May also contain a comma separated list of additional allowed referrer hosts
>      3) If set to 'disabled' no referrer checking will be performed at all